# Android MediaPlayer does not start again after being stopped

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I want to play a sound. The first time it works well, but if I stop it and want to restart it nothing happens...Any idea?

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sex);
ImageButton andvib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.vib_toggle);
final AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
andvib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, vol, 0);
        Vibrator vibr = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibr.cancel();
        if(vibrating==false) {
            if(style == 0)
                vibr.vibrate(durat, 0);
            if(style == 1){
                vibr.vibrate(staccato, 0);
            }
            if(style == 2){
                vibr.vibrate(wild, 0);
            }
            try {
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();
            mp.setLooping(true);
            vibrating = true;
        }
        else {
            vibrating = false;
            mp.stop();
            try {
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            vibr.cancel();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

When using MediaPlayer, you should always refer to the state change diagram that you can see here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

As you can see from the diagram, after calling stop() on a MediaPlayer, it goes to the Stopped state and you need to call prepare() again to move it to the Prepared state before calling play().

Remember that preparation may take long, so doing that all the time may cause a poor user experience, especially if you are doing it from the main thread (the UI will freeze while the MediaPlayer is preparing). If you play the sound frequently, you should really only prepare() it once, and then always keep it in the Started, Paused or PlaybackCompleted states.

*Bruno Oliveira, Developer Programs Engineer, Google*

Comment: Okay, sounds good. But everytime I start the sound again I have a prepare() before, so normally It should work.

Comment: @Liam: You don't have one in the code you posted. In your onClick, you need to call mp.prepare() before mp.start(). Otherwise, just use mp.pause() instead of mp.stop(), keeping in mind, of course, that this will continue where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to call `mp.prepare()` before you call `start()` the second time.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of output in your log?

Comment: Nope, I'm testing it on my real phone becaue my eumlator doesnt output sound at al...

Comment: @Liam: You can still get a log while debugging on your device.

Comment: 03-29 15:35:36.871: ERROR/MediaPlayer(225): start called in state 64

This is what I get the second time I want to start it! State 64 tells me the MediaPlayer has died...Well, great :D

Comment: Well, you do have your prepare() within a try/catch, and your start outside of it. If your prepare() call fails, your code will still try to start. I would put your start() call within the try/catch block as well.